# KendoUI security

Tags: security, kendo-ui

I am looking at developing a web application that will need to work with personal health information. I am looking at the possibility to using KendoUI for the interface. However, can it be secured to not allow anyone to cross script, bypass or spoof the javascript code since it is on the client side? Or is it better to stay with standard server side controls that require a postback?

Comment: You cannot rely on the client-side JavaScript to be secure. A knowledgeable user can use a debugger to modify anything on the client side. You need to implement security on the server and validate any inputs to ensure no one is trying to make bogus requests.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks detail, but if you are talking about the Kendo DataSource sending data to the server, it is basically a wrapper around jQuery.ajax, so just about anything you can do with jQuery.ajax() you can do with Kendo DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is the less complicated the security the less reliable it is. Just making a simple call to a datasource in kendo will not be very secure but heading the other way with something like o2auth will be a lot more secure but way harder to implement.I would recommend reading [this](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/oauth-has-ruined-everything/) before you continue down this path. You will have to consider how much effort you are willing to go through to protect your app/website from an encroachment. if this is for a commercial environment you will have to take as much precaution as possible to prevent a security breach.